# Trying to submit html value to curl request for url with php and Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, curl

I was originally working with Jquery to get a url from one $.get function, but the result from the second caused a cross orgin request, because I was trying to search through the url with a url I got from the api.

I want to know if there is a way to post this to PHP and if its possible to submit a var url to a get function with curl to avoid this origin issue and then pull it back to the front end to display in a constructive manner

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $.get({
                url: "http://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/races/",
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(result){
                    result.results.forEach(function(element) {
                        $("#racebox").append('<option value="'+element.url+'">'+element.name+ ' '+'</option>');
                    });

                    $('#racebox').on('change',function(){
                        var raceChoice = $('#racebox').val();
                        console.log(raceChoice);
                        $.get({
                            url: raceChoice,
                            dataType: "JSON",
                            success: function(result){
                                result.starting_proficiencies.forEach(function(element) {
                                    $("#output").append(element.name);
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <select id="racebox">
        </select>
    </form>
    <div id="output"></div>
```

This is the code that gives cross origin issues, I hope to try and build a curl backend to work this information instead.

Answer (score 0):

If it is you who built the api you can add header to eliminate the cross origin.

```
<?php
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
?>
```

You can replace the * by the domain name that host the app that will consume the api

Otherwise then you can use PHP using [Guzzlle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/) instead of curl to consume the API by writing methods that call the API and then use Jquery to call these methods.

But i assume curl is also a way to call the API

Comment: I've looked into Curl but am not sure how to get it working truth be told, if you could link any youtube videos to assist me or anything similar. Also I am not in possession of the API

Comment: I think this link is good enougth to help start http://codular.com/curl-with-php. Let me know if it helps. So to consume the api you use CURL. Then you can use Ajax to call methods you've written to consume the api. Sorry for my english